# mb_strimwidth on implode list

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code which gets a list of terms and seperates them using a slash, e.g.

**test/test/test**

I want to limit that text to 28 characters, I have attempted to use `mb_strimwidth` but I get a **Call to undefined function** where the function name is the output of `$type_seperated`.

```
<?php
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'type', array( "fields" => "names" ) );
$type_seperated = implode('/', $term_list);
if ( ! empty( $term_list ) ) : ?>
    <?php echo mb_strimwidth($type_seperated(), 0, 28, '...'); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php _e( 'N/A', 'text-domain' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is this not possible? Does the $type_seperated output need to be a string? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm that `$type_seperated()` function exists which return strings. If you mistakenly used `parenthesis ()` then remove parenthesis which means it should be like  `<?php echo mb_strimwidth($type_seperated, 0, 28, '...'); ?>`

Comment: Yes it was the damn () !! I had copied this from some other code which used get_the_title() where my variable is and I did not remove the parenthesis - working fine now.